# Setting Android SDK location with lein-droid 0.4.0+

Tags: android, clojure, leiningen

Based on [this `lein-droid` tutorial](https://github.com/alexander-yakushev/events/blob/master/tutorial.md), I put the following in my `~/.lein/profiles.clj` to point to my installation of Android SDK Tools version 24.4.1:

```
{:user {:plugins [ [lein-droid "0.4.0-alpha3"] ]}
 :android-common {:android {:sdk-path "/home/cactus/prog/android/android-sdk-linux_x86"}}}
```

And after that, `lein droid` works; for example, I am able to do

```
$ lein droid new foo com.stackoverflow.foo
```

to create a new project.

However, if I bump the version of the `lein-droid` to 0.4.0 proper, or the latest version 0.4.3, or anything in between, then `lein droid new` becomes unable to pick up the SDK location: after editing `~/.lein/profiles.clj` to be

```
{:user {:plugins [ [lein-droid "0.4.3"] ]}
 :android-common {:android {:sdk-path "/home/cactus/prog/android/android-sdk-linux_x86"}}}
```

then the previous command fails:

```
$ lein droid new foo com.stackoverflow.foo
The value of sdk-path is nil. Abort execution.
```

Comment: what version of the android sdk & tools are you using?

Comment: Android SDK Tools 24.4.1. The Android SDK I am targeting is lein-droid's default one (since I'm not changing it anywhere), which is 15.